# Is the HAL-id shown on a paper awaiting moderation definitive?

Tags: publications, citations, preprint

I deposited a paper on HAL-archive yesterday, and it's now "awaiting moderation", so it's not online yet. It has an assigned HAL-id. I am writing an application that will expire before the HAL deposit is made online, and I need to cite this paper.

Is the ID I'm seeing now definitive? That is, will this id be the same when the paper is made online? Also, the link to the article is the same?

**Note** By HAL id, I mean the resource identifier. Here's an example of a paper that is now online (from https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-03461780v1):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After waiting a few days, I can confirm that the id shown while the deposit was "awaiting moderation", is the same as the final one when the paper is public.